# Using promise inside an async function without async/await?

Tags: angular, asynchronous, async-await, promise

I have an async/await function. How should I rewrite it to stay asynchronous but not use async / await? I would like to use promises, but when I want to rewrite this code, it doesn't work... :/

```js
    fruit = 'apple';
    data: any = {};
      constructor(private http: HttpClient, private storage: Storage) {
      }
    
      async function(ex: string): Promise<{}> {
        ex = ex ? ex : await this.storage.get('ex');
        return new Promise<{}>((resolve) => {
          const path = `./exam/${ex || 'apple'}.json`;
          this.fruit = ex;
          this.storage.set('ex', this.fruit );
          this.http.get<{}>(path).subscribe(
            transition => {
              this.data = Object.assign({}, transition || {});
              return resolve(this.data);
            },
            () => {
              this.data = {};
              return resolve(this.data);
            }
          );
        });
      }
    
      get(): string {
        return this.fruit;
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`async/await` is syntactic sugar on top of the promises and provides a way to handle the asynchronous tasks in a synchronous manner. You can give this a try if it works:

```
async function(ex: string): Promise<{}> {
  ex = ex ? ex : await this.storage.get('ex');
    const path = `./exam/${ex || 'apple'}.json`;
    this.fruit = ex;
    this.storage.set('ex', this.fruit );
    try {
      const result = await this.http.get<{}>(path).toPromise();
      this.data = Object.assign({}, result || {});
      return this.data
    } catch (error) {
       console.log(`An error occured ${error}`);
    }
  
}
```

Note: It is always good to use either async/await or then/catch.

Comment: I tried this solution, but it didn't work .

Comment: Did you get any error? First of all how are you calling this function as it is not named?

Comment: I named the function like currentlyUse and then in the component I called it like this: this.fruitService.currentlyUse(this.fruit), I didn't get error, but unfortunately I still got null value, the template didn't show the value. Did I call the function wrong?

Comment: Are you sure you are getting data from the service? Why don't you put a debugger in the function and check how does it getting data and returning?

Comment: I did it, and the problem is between this.fruit = ex;
    this.storage.set('ex', this.fruit ); these two lines. When I have this.fruit = ex I still have a value, but when I go to the next statement I get a null value and dont know why

Comment: So, You need to figure it out and once you do it. The code in the answer will work if not let me know.